# number of ways to split n distinguishable objects into k indistinct sets - allowing for sets with 0 objects

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

After throughout searching both on this site and others I cannot seem to find a good explanation of how to solve this problem. I understand that if the objects are indistinguishable then it is a simple 'stars and bars' example. And that if all sets have at least one object then it is solved by the Stirling number of the second kind, but I am having trouble extending this to include empty sets. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The number of subsets with $k$ elements of a set of $n$ elements is ${n\choose k}$. I don't know if that's relevant here, though.

Comment: If $0\le k_0<k$ boxes are empty, $S(n,k-k_0)$ counts it (where $S(n,k)$ denotes stirling number of second kind). Are you looking for a closed form for $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}S(n,k-i)$?

Comment: If you allow "empty pieces", any number will do (just put all elements into one piece, and fill up with empty ones).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was being rather dense. It seems reasonable to allow for empty sets you would just sum over all k as @talegari suggests.